# Gatsby & Netlify - adding multiple images via cloudinary

Tags: markdown, gatsby, cloudinary, netlify

I have a Netlify/Gatsby test site setup connected via github repo.
My goal is to upload multiple images in the Netlify CMS. I implemented the cloudinary plugin for this.
This works in Netlify CMS when i create a new page with content, i can select multiple images through the cloudinary plugin. Once i publish, it automatically creates a markdown file with all the content.
Example of the markdown file generated:

```
path: /blog/first-post
date: 2020-04-20T17:20:52.595Z
title: First blog post!
media:
  - >-
    https://res.cloudinary.com/dzmtikrn1/image/upload/v1587474425/IMG_20180715_141255_vux692.jpg
  - >-
    https://res.cloudinary.com/dzmtikrn1/image/upload/v1587474426/IMG-20180713-WA0003_fimfc4.jpg
---
test 2
```

Now with graphQL i want to query this media data but it isn't there when queried.
I tried this with one image and that works but once i add multiple it doesn't.

Part of my config.yml:

```
media_library:
  name: cloudinary
  config:
    cloud_name: 
    api_key: 

collections:
  - name: blog
    label: Blog
    folder: blog
    create: true
    fields:
      - { name: path, label: Path }
      - { name: date, label: Date, widget: datetime }
      - { name: title, label: Title }
      - { name: body, label: Body, widget: markdown }
      - label: "Media"
        name: "media"
        widget: "image"
        allow_multiple: true
        media_library:
          config:
            multiple: true
```

Is it the formatting of the markdown or am i missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap it like this

```
- {
          label: Media,
          name: media,
          widget: image,
          allow_multiple: true,
          media_library: { name: cloudinary, output_filename_only: true },
        }
```

then on your GraphQl query just include
`media`

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexPageTemplate {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "index-page" } }) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        media
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 2048, quality: 100) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }     
  }
`;
```